# Multiple validation criteria in SmartyValidate plugin

Tags: php, smarty

How I can check my form data with multiple SmartyValidate options? For example, 'isEmpty' and 'isInt'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not very comfortable, but the best I could finde:

```
{if $var eq '' and $var|string_format:"%d" eq $var}
```

Maybe it would be better to check with PHP and assign the result to a Smarty variable.

Answer (score 0):

was looking for same this.

SmartyValidate (v3 in 2013), docs say:

```
"Multiple validators may be used for one field. Once one validator fails,
the remaining validators for that field are ignored. A "halt" parameter can
also stop validation on remaining fields."
```

Sounds like this is your answer although I have not been able yet to find an example-of...